# Added two libraries and now project won't compile

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, styles

I tried following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4o9zFfyIM4 and after I added the two libraries(RecyclerView and CardView) he instructed to add, my project won't compile anymore. I have had countless errors since then with styles, colours and what not.
I have those now:

1. style attribute attr/colorAccent not found
2. style attribute/colorPrimaryDark not found
3. style attribute/colorPrimary not found
4. resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar not found
5. failed linking references

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3f51b5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

The project worked perfectly fine before I added these two libraries and now they have messed up everything. I am really desperate here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

1. Open the build.gradle file for your app module.

[image]

2. Add the support library to the dependencies section.

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
   }
   ```

Further reading:

- [Create a Card-View based layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview)
- [Create a List with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)
- [Add Import CardView RecyclerView support library in Android Studio](https://www.android-examples.com/add-import-cardview-recyclerview-support-library-in-android-studio/)

Comment: That saved me! I did not have the 'compile appcomat' thing, and now after I have added it it runs perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: So you were missing `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`? Also `compile` will become deprecated, so consider using `implementation`. ( starting with Gradle 3.0.0)

Comment: Yeah, I was missing exactly that. Once I implemented it in my build.gradle file it all worked like a charm.

Comment: @Tomer I'll update my answer then. Good luck with your application! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both libraries have the same version code.

Comment: I erased both libraries the moment I saw they gave me trouble. They probably changed my xml files. Is it possible to restore my xml files to default? Like the ones I get once I create a new project?

Comment: Right click on your xml file -> Local History -> Show History. You can now see all the changes you've made over time. You will be able to revert to a previous version.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. But people suggested to use this Invalidate Caches / Restart thing, so I did. And not my entire local history is gone.
Did that before I knew it was possible to roll the files back.

Comment: Try adding both libraries back in your gradle with the same (up to date) version numbers. If this solves your problem, please accept my answer as solution.

Comment: I tried, still gave me the same problem. What fixed it was adding a compilation of appcompat in the current version. Thank you for your time, though!